# Is there any hope to solve this parametric integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have this complicated parametric integral

$\int\exp \left(a \left(\frac{b}{(c+2 d (x+1))^4}-\frac{\left(\frac{f}{(c+2 d (x+1))^2}+e\right)^2}{4 (g+x+2)^2}\right)\right) \, dx=?$

I appreciate any hints or comments on how I can solve it.

---

P.S. I have already asked it in the Mathematica forum; Mathematica
does not give any answer.

```
Integrate[ Exp[a (b/(c + 2 (1 + x) d)^4 - (e + f/(c + 2 (1 + x) d)^2)^2/(
     4 (2 + x + g)^2))],x]
```

Comment: Mathematica has to juggle $7$ extra parameters that it doesn't know anything about. You might get some usable output if you include the `Assumptions`, i.e. `Integrate[func, range, Assumptions -> a > 0 && ...]` *Edit*: Never mind, I see you mentioned trying as much in the MmaSE post. Looks your integral diverges with those conditions.

Comment: You can try to assume $d \ne 0$ and do the substitution $c+2d(x+1)=y$. If you call $\alpha=g+c-1$ and $\beta=\frac{a}{8d}$ you should be able to drop the number of parameters to $5$ instead of $7$. But it looks like the problem is the singularity in $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A theorem of Liouville...
Let $f(x), g(x)$ be rational functions, with $g(x)$ not constant.  If $\int f(x)e^{g(x)}\,dx$ is elementary, then it must be of the form
$$
\int f(x)e^{g(x)}\,dx = R(x)e^{g(x)}+C
$$
for some rational function.  That is, there exists a rational fuction $R(x)$ so that $f(x) = R'(x)+R(x)g'(x)$.

reference:
*Marchisotto, Elena Anne; Zakeri, Gholam-Ali*, [**An invitation to integration in finite terms**](https://doi.org/10.2307/2687614), Coll. Math. J. 25, No. 4, 295-308 (1994). [ZBL1291.26013](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1291.26013).---

---

Consider this special case of the OP:
$$
\int \exp\left(1/(2+2x)^4\right)\;dx
$$
In order for this to be elementary, we need a rational function $R(x)$ with
$$
1 = R'(x) - \frac{8R(x)}{(2+2x)^5}
$$
Examination of the possible Laurent series for $R(x)$ near $x=-1$ shows that is impossible.